# What pandas operation will help me do a groupby and aggregate by column combinations?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
   bar  foo   o1   o2 thing
0    1    1  0.0  3.3     a
1    1    1  1.1  4.4     a
2    3    2  2.2  5.5     b
   foo_1_bar_3_o1  foo_1_bar_3_o2  foo_2_bar_3_o1  foo_2_bar_3_o2  \
0             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN   
1             NaN             NaN             2.2             5.5   

   foo_1_bar_1_o1  foo_1_bar_1_o2  foo_2_bar_1_o1  foo_2_bar_1_o2 thing  
0             1.1             7.7             NaN             NaN     a  
1             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN     b
```

The first is my input DataFrame and the second is my desired output DataFrame (`NaN`s could be substituted with 0's).

This should be some sort of a groupby (on column `thing`) and then some kind of an aggregating function on values in the columns `o1` and `o2` that aggregate based on all possible combinations of the values of `foo` and `bar`. Notice that `foo_1_bar_2_o2` is 7.7 because it is the sum over the column `o2` when `foo == 1 && bar == 2` for the group 'a'.

I've tried researching `dcast`, `crosstab`, and `pivot` in `pandas` but none seem to satisfy what I am trying to do.

I wrote base Python code that does what I want, but, again, I would like to translate it to a more friendly format using already existing functions. I don't believe my use-case is obscure enough for this to not be possible.

Below is the base Python code for this operation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({'thing': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 
                   'foo': [1, 1, 2], 
                   'bar': [1, 1, 3], 
                   'o1': [0.0, 1.1, 2.2], 
                   'o2': [3.3, 4.4, 5.5]})

key_columns = ['foo', 'bar']

key_value_pairs = [df[key].values.tolist() for key in key_columns]

key_value_pairs = list(set(itertools.product(*key_value_pairs)))

output_columns = ['o1', 'o2']

def aggregate(df):
  new_columns = []
  for pair in key_value_pairs:
    pair = list(zip(key_columns, pair))
    new_column = '_'.join(['%s_%d' % (key, value) for key, value in pair])
    for o in output_columns:
      criteria = list()
      for key, value in pair:
        criterion = (df[key] == value)
        criteria.append(criterion)
      new_columns.append('%s_%s' % (new_column, o))
      df[new_columns[-1]] = df[np.logical_and.reduce(criteria)][o].sum()
  return df.head(1)[new_columns + ['thing']]

things = df['thing'].value_counts().index.tolist()

groups = df.groupby('thing')

dfs = []
for thing in things:
  dfs.append(aggregate(groups.get_group(thing).reset_index()))
  #print(aggregate(groups.get_group(thing).reset_index(drop=True)))

print(df)
print(pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll still have to use `itertools.product()`, because Pandas isn't designed to think about data that don't exist.  But once you've got those extra combinations defined, you can use `groupby()` and `unstack()` to get the output you're looking for.

Using the `key_value_pairs` you defined:

```
for k,v in key_value_pairs:
    if not len(df.loc[df.foo.eq(k) & df.bar.eq(v)]):
        df = df.append({"foo":k, "bar":v, "o1":np.nan, "o2":np.nan, "thing":"a"}, ignore_index=True)
        df = df.append({"foo":k, "bar":v, "o1":np.nan, "o2":np.nan, "thing":"b"}, ignore_index=True)

df
   bar  foo   o1   o2 thing
0    1    1  0.0  3.3     a
1    1    1  1.1  4.4     a
2    3    2  2.2  5.5     b
3    3    1  NaN  NaN     a
4    3    1  NaN  NaN     b
5    1    2  NaN  NaN     a
6    1    2  NaN  NaN     b
```

Now `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
gb = df.groupby(["thing", "foo", "bar"]).sum().unstack(level=[1,2])
gb.columns = [f"foo_{b}_bar_{c}_{a}" for a,b,c in gb.columns]
```

Output:

```
       foo_1_bar_1_o1  foo_1_bar_3_o1  foo_2_bar_1_o1  foo_2_bar_3_o1  \
thing                                                                   
a                 1.1             NaN             NaN             NaN   
b                 NaN             NaN             NaN             2.2   

       foo_1_bar_1_o2  foo_1_bar_3_o2  foo_2_bar_1_o2  foo_2_bar_3_o2  
thing                                                                  
a                 7.7             NaN             NaN             NaN  
b                 NaN             NaN             NaN             5.5
```

Answer (score 2):

I try create dynamic solution:

```
key_columns = ['foo', 'bar']
output_columns = ['o1', 'o2']
```

First add `key_columns` strings to values with [`radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.radd.html):

```
df[key_columns] = (df[key_columns].astype(str)
                                  .radd(pd.Series(key_columns,index=key_columns) + '_'))

print (df)
     bar    foo   o1   o2 thing
0  bar_1  foo_1  0.0  3.3     a
1  bar_1  foo_1  1.1  4.4     a
2  bar_3  foo_2  2.2  5.5     b
```

Then aggregate by [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) - get `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = df.groupby(['thing'] + key_columns)[output_columns].sum().unstack(key_columns)
print (df)
         o1          o2      
bar   bar_1 bar_3 bar_1 bar_3
foo   foo_1 foo_2 foo_1 foo_2
thing                        
a       1.1   NaN   7.7   NaN
b       NaN   2.2   NaN   5.5
```

Create all possible combinations by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), then [`reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.columns.levels, names=df.columns.names)
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[['o1', 'o2'], ['foo_1', 'foo_2'], ['bar_1', 'bar_3']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[None, 'foo', 'bar'])


df = df.reindex(columns=mux).reorder_levels(key_columns + [None], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Last remove `MultiIndex` by `map` with `join`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  thing  foo_1_bar_1_o1  foo_1_bar_1_o2  foo_1_bar_3_o1  foo_1_bar_3_o2  \
0     a             1.1             7.7             NaN             NaN   
1     b             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN   

   foo_2_bar_1_o1  foo_2_bar_1_o2  foo_2_bar_3_o1  foo_2_bar_3_o2  
0             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN  
1             NaN             NaN             2.2             5.5
```

Comment: That is strong Pandas-fu.